# HTML animate "ghost-img" when dragging element

Tags: css, html, animation, web, drag

It's there any way to animate the "ghost image" when dragging the element?

Just like Google Drive, drag the files will trigger cool effect. I tried to add the CSS animation to the `ghost-img`, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ryan119/mdvrkaer/1/) but it's not work.

Comment: fiddle here.
https://jsfiddle.net/ryan119/mdvrkaer/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go this way https://jsfiddle.net/mdvrkaer/4/ :
You miss the "**drag**" event. to move the ghost, make him follow the mouse cursor...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    dragAndDrop();

       $('#ghost-img').hide();
});

function dragAndDrop(){

    var dragElement = document.getElementById('row-1');

    dragElement.addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt) {    

           $('#ghost-img').show();

        //ghost image
        var crt = document.getElementById('ghost-img').cloneNode(true);
        crt.style.position = "absolute"; 
        crt.style.top = "0px";      
        crt.style.right = "0px";
        crt.style.zIndex = -1;
        document.body.appendChild(crt);

        evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage (crt, 0, 0);


     },false);


     dragElement.addEventListener("drag",function(evt) {    

        $('.ghost').css('top', evt.pageY);
        $('.ghost').css('left', evt.pagex);

     },false);
     dragElement.addEventListener("dragend",function(evt) {    

        $('.ghost').hide();

     },false);




}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   This is exactly what I want.
update the fiddle here .
https://jsfiddle.net/ryan119/t06zj4rm/